# Unresolved Externals - Enums within static classes

Tags: c++, enums, linker

I have no idea why my code isn't working, just started learning C++ and all the namespace/header files etc..

I have a main function:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Game::Start();
    return 0;
}
```

Which calls a static function within game to start.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"
void Game::Start(void)
{
    _gameState = ShowingMenu;

    while(IsExiting())
    {
        switch(_gameState)
        {
            case ShowingMenu:
                ShowMenu();
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Now whereever I use the enum GameState (as you will see from the header) I get:

```
Unresolved external symbol private static enum Game::GameState Game::GameState
```

This is the Game.h

```
#pragma once

class Game {
public:
    static void Start();
private:
    static void GameLoop();
    static bool IsExiting();
    static void ShowMenu();
    enum GameState { Uninitialized, ShowingMenu, Dealing, DealerTurn, PlayerTurn, Betting, Exiting };
    static GameState _gameState;
};
```

Not sure why this is not working, the only solution was to take out the whole enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you define `_gameState` in a single translation unit (probably within `Game.cpp`):

```
Game::GameState Game::_gameState;
```

The `static GameState _gameState;` in your class definition is only a declaration, so the member must be defined too. See [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html) for more details.

Comment: Hmm.. where is that usually defined? Before or after functions?

Comment: @user2011736 It tends to be before but I don't think there's any reason it has to be.

Comment: Declare it in your .CPP file (just before your constructor). In your case, between **#include "Game.h"** and **Game::Start(void)**.